# Granting unmask permission to SQL server user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have  two different users 'sales' and 'logistics' . I have a table 'accounts' where some columns are masked (using dynamic data masking functions). 
Both users have SELECT permission on the table 'accounts'.
The 'sales' user has UNMASK permission on a table 'accounts' but the 'logistics' user does not.
But, the logistics user is also able to see the columns unmasked despite not having UNMASK permission.
How do I fix this???